# How to print continuous page size in itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, printing, controller, itext

I have to print an Invoice, but, the problem is that I need to specify the dimensions of the paper, but, I don't know the height of my report, it will be printed for a continuous pos printer.

This is how I create the document:

```
    Rectangle envelope = new Rectangle(216, 14400);//margenes

    Document doc = new Document(envelope, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I didn't see anything about this in the official documentation, so, if somebody can help.

This is the rest of my code, if it works for somebody:

```
    public async Task<FileResult> CreatePdf(int id)
    {
        MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
        StringBuilder status = new StringBuilder("");
        DateTime dTime = DateTime.Now;
        //file name to be created   
        string strPDFFileName = string.Format("SamplePdf" + dTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "-" + ".pdf");
        Rectangle envelope = new Rectangle(216, 14400);//margenes
       // Document doc = new Document(envelope, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Document doc = new Document(envelope, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        //Document doc = new Document();
        doc.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
        //Create PDF Table with 5 columns  
        PdfPTable tableLayout = new PdfPTable(5);
        doc.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
        //Create PDF Table  

        //file will created in this path  
        string strAttachment = Server.MapPath("~/Downloadss/" + strPDFFileName);


        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, workStream).CloseStream = false;
        doc.Open();

        //Add Content to PDF   
        doc.Add(await Add_Content_To_PDF(tableLayout, id));

        // Closing the document  
        doc.Close();

        byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
        workStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
        workStream.Position = 0;

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Creates a FileStreamResult object using the Stream object, the content type,
        //     and the target file name.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   fileStream:
        //     The stream to send to the response.
        //
        //   contentType:
        //     The content type (MIME type)
        //
        //   fileDownloadName:
        //     The file name to use in the file-download dialog box that is displayed in the
        //     browser.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The file-stream result object.
        //protected internal virtual FileStreamResult File(Stream fileStream, string contentType, string fileDownloadName);
        return File(workStream, "application/pdf", strPDFFileName);

    }
    public async Task<int> GetAuthorId()
    {
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        return await UsersHelper.GetAuthorId(currentUser.Email);
    }
    protected async Task<PdfPTable> Add_Content_To_PDF(PdfPTable tableLayout, int id)
    {
       // float[] headers = { 50, 24, 45, 35, 50 }; //Header Widths 
        float[] headers = { 105, 45, 45,0,0 }; //Header Widths  
        tableLayout.SetWidths(headers); //Set the pdf headers  
        tableLayout.WidthPercentage = 100; //Set the PDF File witdh percentage  
        tableLayout.HeaderRows = 1;
        //Add Title to the PDF file at the top  

        var salesDetails =   _db.SalesDetails.ToList<SalesDetail>();
        var salesDetails2 = await _db.SalesDetails.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=> x.SalesId==id);
        var authorid = await GetAuthorId();

        var report = await _db.Reports.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.AuthorId == authorid);

        if (report == null)
        {
            // return RedirectToAction($"Create/{id}");
        }
        //HEADER BEGINS
        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(report.Header1, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
        {
            Colspan = 12,
            Border = 0,
            PaddingBottom = 5,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
        });
        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(report.Header2, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
        {
            Colspan = 12,
            Border = 0,
            PaddingBottom = 5,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
        });
        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(report.Header3, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
        {
            Colspan = 12,
            Border = 0,
            PaddingBottom = 5,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
        });
        //HEADER ENDS
        //Sales Details Begins
        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" _________________", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
        {
            Colspan = 12,
            Border = 0,
            PaddingBottom = 5,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
        });
        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" No. Factura......:  " + salesDetails2.Sales.SalesInvoiceNo, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
        {
            Colspan = 12,
            Border = 0,
            PaddingBottom = 5,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
        });
        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" Cliente..........:  " + salesDetails2.Sales.Remarks, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
        {
            Colspan = 12,
            Border = 0,
            PaddingBottom = 5,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
        });
        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" Estatus Factura..:  " + salesDetails2.Sales.Status.Name, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
        {
            Colspan = 12,
            Border = 0,
            PaddingBottom = 5,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
        });
        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" Fecha Compra.....:  " + salesDetails2.Sales.SalesDate, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
        {
            Colspan = 12,
            Border = 0,
            PaddingBottom = 5,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
        });
        //Sales Details Ends
        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" __________________", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
        {
            Colspan = 12,
            Border = 0,
            PaddingBottom = 5,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
        });

        ////Add header  
         AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Producto");
         AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Cantidad");
         AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Precio");
          AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "");
        AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "");
        //tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Producto", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK)))
        //{
        //    HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
        //    Padding = 5,
        //    BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(255, 255, 255)
        //});
        //tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cantidad", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK)))
        //{
        //    HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
        //    Padding = 5,
        //    BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(255, 255, 255)
        //});
        //tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Precio", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK)))
        //{
        //    HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
        //    Padding = 5,
        //    BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(255, 255, 255)
        //});
        //tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Precio", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK)))
        //{
        //    HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
        //    Padding = 5,
        //    BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(255, 255, 255)
        //});
        //tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Precio", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK)))
        //{
        //    HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
        //    Padding = 5,
        //    BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(255, 255, 255)
        //});
        ////Add body  

        foreach (var emp in salesDetails)
        {

             //AddCellToBody(tableLayout, emp.SalesDetailId.ToString());
             AddCellToBody(tableLayout, emp.Product.Name);
            AddCellToBody(tableLayout, emp.Quantity.ToString());
             AddCellToBody(tableLayout, emp.Product.SellPrice.ToString());
            AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "");
            AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "");
            //tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(emp.Product.Name, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK)))
            //{
            //    HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
            //    Padding = 5,
            //    BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(255, 255, 255)
            //});
            //tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(emp.Quantity.ToString(), new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK)))
            //{
            //    HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
            //    Padding = 5,
            //    BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(255, 255, 255)
            //});
            //tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(emp.Product.SellPrice.ToString(), new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK)))
            //{
            //    HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
            //    Padding = 5,
            //    BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(255, 255, 255)
            //});
            //  AddCellToBody(tableLayout, emp.SubTotal.ToString());

        }

        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" Sub Total........:  " + salesDetails2.Sales.SubTotal, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
        {
            Colspan = 12,
            Border = 0,
            PaddingBottom = 5,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
        });
        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" Descuentos.......:  " + salesDetails2.Sales.TotalDiscount, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
        {
            Colspan = 12,
            Border = 0,
            PaddingBottom = 5,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
        });
        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" Cargos...........:  " + salesDetails2.Sales.TotalCharges, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
        {
            Colspan = 12,
            Border = 0,
            PaddingBottom = 5,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
        });
        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" Total a Pagar....:  " + salesDetails2.Sales.Total, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
        {
            Colspan = 12,
            Border = 0,
            PaddingBottom = 5,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
        });
        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" Monto Pagado.....:  " + salesDetails2.Sales.PaidAmount, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
        {
            Colspan = 12,
            Border = 0,
            PaddingBottom = 5,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
        });
        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" Monto Adeudado...:  " + salesDetails2.Sales.DebtAmount, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
        {
            Colspan = 12,
            Border = 0,
            PaddingBottom = 5,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
        });
        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(report.Footer1, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
        {
            Colspan = 12,
            Border = 0,
            PaddingBottom = 5,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
        });
        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(report.Footer2, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
        {
            Colspan = 12,
            Border = 0,
            PaddingBottom = 5,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
        });
        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(report.Footer3, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
        {
            Colspan = 12,
            Border = 0,
            PaddingBottom = 5,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
        });
        return tableLayout;
    }
    // Method to add single cell to the Header  
    private static void AddCellToHeader(PdfPTable tableLayout, string cellText)
    {

        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.YELLOW)))
        {
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
            Padding = 5,
            BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(128, 0, 0)
        });
    }

    // Method to add single cell to the body  
    private static void AddCellToBody(PdfPTable tableLayout, string cellText)
    {
        tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK)))
        {
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
            Padding = 5,
            BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(255, 255, 255)
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you chose to use an old iText version? Because there is an answer on the official web site on how to do this with version 7. Unfortunately, that answer can't be used for the old version that you are using.

Comment: im using old version because is the only example that i have found

Comment: That's odd. How come? Did you visit the official web site? If so, can you tell me what we can do to improve the web site so that people don't use the wrong version?

Comment: theres not examples, for newbies programers like me, Im just want to find something that work, but i dont have too much programer skills, so I found this code that work, on the oficial page, theres not examples for people like me

Comment: So just to be clear: are you claiming that the Jump-start tutorial doesn't contain any simple examples? We invested in both a [Java](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial) and a [C#](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net-version) version. Are you saying that was a bad investment? Or are you saying that we should have more paying users so thar we can increase the educational budget? Would you be willing to pay for better documentation? Are you going to pay for your use of iText?

Comment: This is a great invested for users like me, that dont have too much programers skills, so, for that reason, i want to put to work the sample that i ready have, because, like I told you, I dont have too much skills to understand those examples (java samples, because i dindt find the C# samples until now) so, the thing here is, try to put to work something that i ready know that work (the sample that i have) because this tool is awsome... and, of course, i could pay if i solve this issue